# Echo a custom page's custom field outside the loop

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I have a custom page template with certain custom fields. I want to display these custom fields outside the loop, but within the same page.

This one works:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta( '244', 'custom_field_name', true ) ?>
```

But I want to to work dynamically, without me entering the actual ID of the page.

How can I call the page ID in the echo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
<?php

    global $wp_query;

    $postid = $wp_query->post->ID;

    echo get_post_meta($postid, 'Your-Custom-Field', true);

    wp_reset_query();

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If this call is in the loop, replace the id with function `get_the_ID`, this function retrieves the ID of the current item in the WordPress Loop.

```
<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'custom_field_name', true ) ?>
```

See: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_ID/

---

If this call is in the single page, replace the id with object item `$post->ID`.

```
$post = get_post();
<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'custom_field_name', true ) ?>
```

See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post

---

Also, you can get the access to the post via global variable `$post`.

```
$post = get_post();
<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'custom_field_name', true ) ?>
```

See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables